# Как изменить размер области ClipPath

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

У меня есть такой код:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clipped-img {
  clip-path: url('#header-clip-svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">

  <!--clipping SVG-->
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="header-clip-svg">
        <path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <!-- clipped image-->
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
  
</div>
```

Я хочу увеличить размеры формы обрезки, чтобы она имела ширину цветной зеленой области.
Есть ли способ сделать это?

Comment: [Тут на мете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394396/qa-copied-to-ru-stackoverflow-is-this-a-known-behavior) Просят добавить аттрибуты оригинала на аглийском

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60491855/7394871

Comment: @DmitriiZ. спасибо, что напомнили. Обычно ставлю ассоциацию, а здесь пропустил

Answer (score 3):

> [Перевод ответа @Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/7394871) на вопрос EnSO [How to resize
>   ClipPath area of SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60491855/7394871)

Вы можете использовать форму обрезки как маску и легко настроить её, как `background-image`.
 Просто убедитесь, что вы установили правильное значение для `viewBox`:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen; 
  margin:5px;
}

.clipped-img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>' ) 
               center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>' ) 
               center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:500px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:150px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
</div>
```

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/7394871) @Temani Afif

Comment: Интересно,  а блок div можно таким образом обрезать?